# Multiple __COUNTER__ C

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, counter

I'm playing around with the preprocessor and c. Trying to implement my own event and hierarchy system. 
However I'm facing a problem. I'm trying to statically define my "modules" which can be initialized, and some events which also are statically defined in advance. For the events I'm using **COUNTER** which works beautiful. But I don't want to mix up module id's and event id's.

So a simplified version of what I'm trying to achieve:

hierarchy.h

```
#define HIERARCHY_DEFINE(NAME) int hierarchyId = __COUNTER__
```

event.h

```
#define EVENT_REGISTER(NAME) int eventId = __COUNTER__
```

main.c

```
#include "event.h"
#include "hierarchy.h"

EVENT_REGISTER(EventOne);
HIERARCHY_DEFINE(ModuleOne);
EVENT_REGISTER(EventTwo);

int main(void){
    printf("events(%d, %d) modules(%d)\n",EventOne,EventTwo,ModuleOne);
    return 1;
}
```

This will print out:

```
events(0, 2) modules(1)
```

When I'm trying to achieve:

```
events(0, 1) modules(0)
```

I've looked around and people saying I can't create a counter on my own. And seen the boost counter, but that doesn't achieve what I want either.

Does anybody have an idea how I could  handle this situation?

Thanks!

Edit:

slight adition of what my code actually looks like

```
struct Event{
    uint8_t eventId;
    uint8_t * data;
    const char * description;
};

#define EVENT_REGISTER(eventName, desc)\
static Event eventName = {.eventId = __COUNTER__, .data = 0, .description = desc }




EVENT_REGISTER(Timer_5, "Timer 5 hZ");
```

Comment: If the IDs are statically defined, they could go into an `enum`, right?

Comment: So you want one counter for events, and one for modules, and those two counters should be separate? Then why not just use two variables, initialized to zero and incremented in your macros? E.g. `int eventId = eventIdCounter++;`

Comment: They could, yes, but I like to keep it as easy as possible to register an event. Only one line is sufficient now. Don't want to have to change an enum all the time I add or remove or change an event

Comment: Sorry, I left out some detail. I'm using a struct to hold the information. And I need constants to initialize that. Compiler restrictions :( . So i can't use two variables

Comment: i think someone should mention that you're trying to [re-invent the wheel](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/signals/tutorial.html), which is **always** a bad idea and doesnt even serve an educational purpose.

Comment: For an actual project with the goal of achieving I would certainly not reinvent the wheel. But the goal of this project is learning.

Comment: you wont learn much from the wheel - it has always been like that. Pupils dont learn from their own wheels **but** they **do** learn from finished cars or even car dealerships. If you want to learn you need to attack worthy tutorials, do proven exercises and **read** a lot - if you're autodidactic you might as well have a detailed look into completed libraries, sometimes you discover fascinating *(or shocking)* stuff in there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must either:

- assign ids at runtime,
- assign ids by hands
- or keep all events and modules definitions in one place.

Consider that you have `a.c` and `b.c`, and they contains some `EventA` and `EventB` definitions respectively. As they are separate compilation units, there is no way compiler can assign non-overlapping ids to them. Compiling `b.c`, it doesn't even know there is another `a.c` where id `1` is already assigned.

For the first one, have a `RegisterEvent` function like so:

```
void RegisterEvent(Event* event){
  static int nextEventId = 0;
  event->eventId = nextEventId;
}
```

And call it for every `Event` you need.

Second one is obvious, but tedious and error prone.

For the third solution, you can use an [X macro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro).

Have a X-list of all your events:

```
#define EventList \
  Event(FirstEvent, "FirstEvent") \
  Event(Timer_1, "Timer 1 hZ") \
  ... 
  Event(Timer_5, "Timer 5 hZ")
```

Now, in a header there you are going to declare all your events (say, `events.h`):

```
#define Event(name, desc) EventID ## name,
enum EventID{
 EventIDZero = 0,
 EventList 
 EventIDCount
};
#undef Event

#define Event(name, desc) \
  extern Event name;
EventList
#undef Event
```

And in a single compilation unit where your event definitions will reside (say, `events.c`):

```
#include "events.h"

#define Event(name, desc) \
  Event name = {.eventId = EventID ## name, .data = 0, .description = desc };
EventList
#undef Event
```

After macro expansion, `events.c` looks like (slightly edited for readability):

```
enum EventID{
 EventIDZero = 0,
 EventIDFirstEvent, EventIDTimer_1, EventIDTimer_5,
 EventIDCount
};

extern Event FirstEvent; 
extern Event Timer_1; 
extern Event Timer_5;

Event FirstEvent = {.eventId = EventIDFirstEvent, .data = 0, .description = "FirstEvent" }; 
Event Timer_1 = {.eventId = EventIDTimer_1, .data = 0, .description = "Timer 1 hZ" }; 
Event Timer_5 = {.eventId = EventIDTimer_5, .data = 0, .description = "Timer 5 hZ" };
```

Same thing goes for modules.

Comment: Thanks for that X-Macro! That's the kind of stuff I hope on finding out about by doing this. Although it might not be the best approach in this case

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have additional requirements for the identifiers, the following will do:

definitions.inc

```
EVENT_REGISTER(Timer_5, "Timer 5 Hz")
EVENT_REGISTER(Timer_10, "Timer 10 Hz")
MODULE_REGISTER(Module_SSH)
MODULE_REGISTER(Module_NCO)
#undef EVENT_REGISTER
#undef MODULE_REGISTER
```

app.c

```
#define EVENT_REGISTER(a, d) a,
#define MODULE_REGISTER(a)
enum events {
#include "definitions.inc"
};

#define EVENT_REGISTER(a, d)
#define MODULE_REGISTER(a) a,
enum modules {
#include "definitions.inc"
};

struct Event {
    uint8_t event_id;
    uint8_t *data;
    const char *description;
};

#define MODULE_REGISTER(a)
#define EVENT_REGISTER(a, d) static struct Event Event_##a = { .event_id = a, \
    .data = NULL, \
    .description = d \
};
#include "definitions.inc"


int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("events(%d, %d) modules(%d)\n", Timer_10, Timer_5, Module_SSH);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: That would work, yes, but now I need to maintain two enum lists.

Comment: What kind of maintenance are you referring to?

Comment: Well, I would have to register the event somewhere, and I would have to add it to an enum

Comment: You have to do the typing at some point, you're not getting away from that. Check out the edit.